# typing issue with abstract method in class that is extended from abstracted class

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I currently have trouble with trying to implement a getter from an abstract class/method

```
class Base {
  get base () {
    return "base";
  }
}



class Content1 extends Base {
  get content1 () {
    return "string";
  }
}
class Content2 extends Base {
  get content2 () {
    return 123;
  }
}



class MyBody<T extends typeof Base> {
  protected myContent : T
  constructor (inContent : T) {
    this.myContent = inContent
  }
  get content () {
    return new this.myContent() as InstanceType<T>;
  }
}



abstract class Page<T extends typeof Base> {
  protected myRoot : string
  constructor (inRoot : string) {
    this.myRoot = inRoot;
  }
  abstract get body () : MyBody<T> 
}
class Page1<T extends typeof Base> extends Page<T> {
  get body () { // <----------------- issue here
    return new MyBody(Content1);
  }
}
const p1 = new Page1("abc");
p1.body.content



class NotAbstractedPage { // <------ this is fine however
  protected myRoot : string
  constructor (inRoot : string) {
    this.myRoot = inRoot;
  }
  get body () {
    return new MyBody(Content1);
  }
}
const np = new NotAbstractedPage("abc");
np.body.content.content1;
```

The error is

```
Property 'body' in type 'Page1<T>' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Page<T>'.
  Type 'MyBody<typeof Content1>' is not assignable to type 'MyBody<T>'.
    Type 'typeof Content1' is not assignable to type 'T'.
      'typeof Content1' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'typeof Base'.(2416)
(property) Page1<T extends typeof Base>.body: MyBody<typeof Content1>
```

I tried converting it to `typeof MyBody<T>` but that just gave more errors.

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.2#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8CwAoa0DmCAu0ARotABQCUKGWWATvgK60B20ARMRAmwNzXQBfDEPQYx6UJBgBhAPbM8CBQEZoCAB6LmAExjwuVTDnzRg8rXlUVDNaPTxNWbCHloBLZtl78RIyVGg5BSU8ACY1TSVdOBI0I1wCM2CFcOs423tHaGVQgGY%20I19xcX8YAFkAT1hZbQqAHgAVCK1ovAqABwRZADMYrgA%20G2h22llFYEVtaABbCqCLaAAuaAb%20JJdaBgnZWjIPeZCllcp0mjwACzcIADpZg4VoAF5offMQn34E0zeHtP46RgsaDMBAAd2gFyutzmPzw1kg0AAkswXGBmMAEA0OghGv0ClgiqIiRgwIQNmAJqZwAEAApgXCNZpRGBtTo9PoIQanEZjBATBBTWYAJVkYyOGw82DW8g2WzwOz2zBFYuWEs8J3%20EMuN2FooIzw8yrw%20ME-FJ5MpX0INQqZEoy0q1VquOEGFK0DpuGUjI0LRZ2PZ%20k5TJ0ME9OIaXM%20JmttTtQwBDiBIPBjptpHulnIJsJ6wI7VUzxTHvpCGUpDYpOAbGzGAL11jFWuSQsxSJ7oAcmMAIJk1wUybhoY88aTGYVI3i1yS6Uo1xyhWkQ16qfudUJrVQ3Vig1KvU56MERvx06JrLFtO1DOw5S1wquiQygjMdpPYFg6BdvC9i2D0sVqsawKF8GxtZtYXA5JLB4IA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I realized I just needed to put the intended type into the extended part.

Original

```
class Page1<T extends typeof Base> extends Page<T> {
  get body () {
    return new MyBody(Content1);
  }
}
```

Fix

```
class Page1 extends Page<typeof Content1> {
  get body () {
    return new MyBody(Content1);
  }
}
```